# ORA-00920: invalid relational operator while using case

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a code using oracle developer to find if there is a login from a device for 3 consecutive days, I'm writing a code using case function but it is giving me invalid relational operator error. I don't know where I am wrong.

thanks in advance

```
SELECT *FROM
(SELECT a.*,substr(TEXT_USERNAME,2,length(TEXT_USERNAME)-2), row_number() 
over (partition by trunc(DTIME_LOGIN) order by TEXT_USERNAME ) rn

 FROM 
  OWNER_DWH.F_HOSEL_USER_LOGIN_TT a)

 WHERE

  (CASE WHEN trunc(dtime_login)=trunc(sysdate-1) then  'y'
  ELSE 'n' END ) D1
  and 
   (CASE WHEN trunc(dtime_login)=trunc(sysdate-2) then  'y'
  ELSE 'n' END) D2
  and 
   (CASE WHEN trunc(dtime_login)=trunc(sysdate-3) then  'y'
  ELSE 'n' END) D3
```

Comment: What should "...WHERE D1 AND D2 AND D3" mean? How should it be interpreted by SQL?

Answer (score 1):

This fixes your syntax error.  But the code will return no rows because your logic is wrong:

```
WHERE 'y' = (CASE WHEN trunc(dtime_login) = trunc(sysdate-1) then 'y' ELSE 'n' END) AND
      'y' = (CASE WHEN trunc(dtime_login) = trunc(sysdate-2) then 'y' ELSE 'n' END) AND
      'y' = (CASE WHEN trunc(dtime_login) = trunc(sysdate-3) then 'y' ELSE 'n' END)
```

I would suggest that you ask *another* question with sample data and desired results and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: what should I do to make column containing value `Y` and `N` for `sysdate-1, syadate-2 and sysdate-3`

Comment: @VBAToddler . . . Ask another question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GodonLinoff sure will do

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing a query, you are asking a question of the data.  The predicate, or where clause, is the specific question to limit the rows you want to return.  This ...

```
(CASE WHEN trunc(dtime_login)=trunc(sysdate-1) then  'y'
      ELSE 'n' END ) D1
```

... is actually a valid predicate.  Here, you are running a `CASE` statemtent that will return a value, but the value is never compared to a constant or other value.  Instead, you seem to be trying to assign an alias, which is only for the select column.

Perhaps you were thinking about something like the following.  Here, the `CASE` statement is evaluated and the resulting value is tested against the value 'y'.

```
(CASE WHEN trunc(dtime_login)=trunc(sysdate-1) then  'y'
      ELSE 'n' END ) = 'y'
```

Comment: The first example is a valid SQL *expression*, not a predicate. Your second example is a valid predicate.